# Unwrap optional in inline conditional statement

Tags: swift

In Swift, is there a way to unwrap an optional in an inline conditional statement? There are cases when the nil coalescing operator `??` doesn't work, such as when the optional being unwrapped has to be used in a function.

For example, suppose f has signature `func f(a:Int) -> Bool` and reading `A ? B : C` as `if A { B } else { C }` then something like the following might make sense:

```
var c:Int?
let a:Bool = let b = c ? f(b) : false
```

Obviously this can be done using `!`:

```
let a:Bool = b != nil ? f(b!) : false
```

But I prefer to avoid using `!` where possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  `map` can be applied to an optional and the closure is executed if the value is not `nil`, otherwise `nil` is returned.  You can then use the *nil coalescing operator* to unwrap the result of `map`:

```
let a = b.map { f($0) } ?? false
```

As @Alexandar noted in the comments, since your function takes just one argument, you can write `map` just passing the function name:

```
let a = b.map(f) ?? false
```

---

**Complete example**

```
func f(_ a:Int) -> Bool {
    return a > 17
}

var b:Int? = 18

let a1 = b.map(f) ?? false

print(a1)  // true

b = nil

let a2 = b.map(f) ?? false

print(a2)  // false
```

---

> ```
> func map<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> Evaluates the given closure when this Optional instance is not nil, passing the unwrapped value as a parameter.
>   Use the map method with a closure that returns a nonoptional value.

---

Comment: It can even be simplified to remove an unnecessary closure layer: `b.map(f) ?? false`

Comment: Thanks for the answer vacawama. Thanks @Alexander, I like that extra neatness

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander.  I updated my answer with your suggestion.